# regular expression for comments in java

Tags: java, regex

I am using this regular expression  to replace whatever character is between /* and */ including line breaks(Actually I want to replace all the comments in code) But that does not work, any ideas?

```
$replaceAll("(?s)/\ \ * . * \ \ * / ", "")
```

Comment: Why not just use sed?

Comment: You need a primitive parser / lexer, otherwise you'll blow away "comments" embedded inside of strings that are therefore not actually comments.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: That's not true. In Java, neither comments nor strings can be nested inside either comments or strings. Something like `/* foo "/*bar*/" baz */` means `" baz */`.

Comment: could you add the text example?

Comment: Don't forget single-line comments starting with `//`.

Comment: Here is a good writeup although it does not deal with `//`: http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html It still does not handle comments in strings (and the author acknowledges that), but that's the best you can do with a single regular expression. You would have to implement at least some amount of parsing to handle comments in strings.

Comment: @Jason I would upvote this if it were a full answer, it seems like the only right answer, it would just need a fuller "proof" if you will.